# Orbits of $S_n$ have size $1$, $2$ or $\geq n$, without simplicity of $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof

Let $n \geq 5$ and let $X$ be a set on which $S_n$ acts. I'd like to show that every $S_n$-orbit has size $1$, $2$ or $\geq n$.

This isn't hard if I know that $A_n$ is simple: For $x \in X$, let $\text{Stab}(x)$ be the stabilizer of $x$. Then $|S_n x| = [S_n : \text{Stab}(x)]$. See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255268/448).

However, proofs that $A_n$ are simple are all a bit messy. I'd like a really quick, slick way to do this, for a student who has seen groups and group actions (and hence subgroups and orbit stabilizer), but doesn't know $A_n$ is simple. Any ideas?

---

A note as to motivation: The way that I understand the cubic and biquadratic formulas is using [resolvents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_(Galois_theory)). We start with a degree $n$ polynomial, for $n=3$ or $4$, with roots $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, ..., $\alpha_n$. We find a multivariate polynomial $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ such that the orbit of $f$ under the $S_n$ action on $\mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ has size $d<n$. Then $f(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $d$. For example, with $n=4$, we can find a [cubic equation satisfied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_cubic#Fourth_definition) by $\alpha_1 \alpha_2 + \alpha_3 \alpha_4$. The reason that this method is not useful for $n \geq 5$ is that, for any $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$, either $f$ is symmetric, or $f$ is anti-symmetric, or else $|S_n f| \geq n$.

I think this is a very nice application of group actions. I'd like to be able to discuss it as soon as I introduce group actions, which means before we know that $A_n$ is simple.

Comment: For the specific case $n=5$ you could argue that any $5$-cycle must act trivially, by orbit--stabilizer. Since $(1,2,3,4,5)(5,4,3,1,2) = (1,3,2)$ it follows that any $3$-cycle acts trivially, and since $(1,2,3)(1,2,4) = (1,3)(2,4)$ it follows that any even permutation acts trivially.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks! I had thought of a messier version of this, but this is very streamlined. I can even streamline it a little more: $(12345)(12354) = (13)(24)$. Still leaving the question up to see what people can come up with for larger $n$.

Comment: Isn't this fact in some sense equivalent to determining the normal structure of $S_n$? If $S_n$ has an orbit of size $x$ strictly between $2$ and $n$, then it has a subgroup of index $x$ and the core of this subgroup would be a normal subgroup of index strictly between $2$ and $n!$.

Comment: For example, $S_4$ can act transitively on $3$ points, because it has an exceptional normal subgroup of index $6$.